# Pre loading images into a variable

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I am trying to change an image in my app depending on the position of the phone using the accelerometer. This isn't where I'm stuck, its not to hard to do. 
I have an array of images from my drawable folders that change depending on the angle of the device. This works fine (switching the image of the imageview), with low res images but what would like to know is, is there a way or preloading images in java like I can in JavaScript when creating rollover images. So the hi res images would change seamlessly like the low res images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Create a subclass MyApp of Application.

In MApp.onCreate() you can preload your images; e.g.

```
image1 = getResources().getDrawable (R.drawable.image1);
```

And in your app, you simply do something like

```
image1 = ((MyApp)getApplication()).getImage1();
```

where getImage1 is a getter you provide in MyApp.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Depending on the design and architecture of the app, you could use this same trick in your Activity's onCreate() or some other location as well.

Comment: The problem with putting in your main activity's "main" onCreate is that main.onCreate will get called every time the activity is brought back to life.  Thus, if you have refs from other activities to the images loaded in an earlier main.onCreate, you will end up with multiple copies of the images in memory (the old pointers don't become invalid; they simply keep holding onto old chunks of memory).  Also, when you exit the app, the app doesn't necessarily die and so you really want to use Application.onCreate for truly global stuff.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/luckybilly/PreLoader can resolve your problem.

you can pre-load almost everything you need with PreLoader. And you don`t need to worry about it not completed when you should get it: DataListener.onDataArrived(data) will be called after pre-load is completed